# GET method not supported in SpringFrameWork even though I'm using DELETE instead

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, http, jpa

I'm trying to create a simple web page that allows CRUD operations to be made on a driver class. In my Driver controller class, I have the following functions to delete a driver.

```
@GetMapping("/delete/{id}")
    public String borrarPersona(Model model, @PathVariable Long id){
        Conductor c = condService.recuperarPersona(id);
        model.addAttribute("conductor", c);
        return "person-delete";
    }
    
    @DeleteMapping(value="/confirmDelete")
    public String borrarConfirmado(@Valid Conductor driver, BindingResult result, Model model){
        condService.borrarPersona(driver);
        return "redirect:/conductor/list";
    }
```

Method recuperarPersona(id) is simply to select the driver and pass the data to the HTML page "person-delete".

Here's my HTML file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h1>Conductor</h1>
            <form action="#" th:action="@{/conductor/confirmDelete}" th:object="${conductor}" method="delete">
                <label for="driverFirstName">Nombre: </label>
                <label th:text="*{firstName}" id="driverFirstName"></label><br>
                <label for="driverLastName">Apellido: </label>
                <label th:text="*{lastName}" id="driverLastName"></label><br>
                <label for="driverCedula">Cedula: </label>
                <label th:text="*{cedula}" id="driverCedula"></label><br>
                <label for="driverTelefono">Telefono: </label>
                <label th:text="*{telefono}" id="driverTelefono"></label><br>
                <label for="driverDireccion">Direccion: </label>
                <label th:text="*{direccion}" id="driverDireccion"></label><br>
                <button type="submit">Borrar</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <a th:href="@{/conductor/list}">Cancelar</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

All the information regarding the driver is correctly shown on the page. But when I hit the submit button in order to start the function borrarConfirmado I get the following error.

`This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.`

```
Request method 'GET' not supported
org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported
```

I'm at a loss, since I don't use any GET methods for the submit button on the form, yet it's asking me there's no mapping for a GET method. Am I missing something? Thank you for your time.

Comment: I think `<form>` doesn't support `method="delete"` - only GET and POST.

Comment: @dan1st is correct: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form

Comment: You're both right, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML form does not support the Method delete, it supports only get and post methods in HTML form.